# importa arquivos csv de forma automatica

Tags: python, csv

Tenho uma lista de varios arquivos csv em um único diretório
acontece que a cada 5 min entra mais arquivo nesse diretório

exemplo do arquivo:

DET_Export_LOL-SLA_Traceroute_Active_Test_5_Mins_2020-12-10_18_23_00.csv
DET_Export_LOL-SLA_Traceroute_Active_Test_5_Mins_2020-12-11_18_28_00.csv
DET_Export_LOL-SLA_Traceroute_Active_Test_5_Mins_2020-12-11_18_33_00.csv
DET_Export_LOL-SLA_Traceroute_Active_Test_5_Mins_2020-12-11_18_38_00.csv

esses arquivos a cada 5 min cria um novo.

eu preciso inserir um arquivo desse no python fazer o tratamento de regex que já fiz e depois salvar com outro nome

porem de forma automatica
ex

entra: DET_Export_LOL-SLA_Traceroute_Active_Test_5_Mins_2020-12-10_18_23_00.csv
trata (ja pronto o codigo)
salva

entra DET_Export_LOL-SLA_Traceroute_Active_Test_5_Mins_2020-12-11_18_28_00.csv
trata (ja pronto o codigo)
salva

Comment: Leia sobre padrões de projeto (design pattern) especificamente sobre observável e observador (observer)

Answer (score 1):

Você pode usar a função listdir da biblioteca os

import os

arquivos = os.listdir('Caminho da pasta')

essa função vai retornar uma lista contendo todos os arquivos dentro dessa pasta.
Você pode criar um  função pra pegar esse arquivo e comparar com o que você já usou e usar a biblioteca schedule
Essa schedule não é nativa do python você terá que fazer o download pelo pip.

```
import schedule
import time

schedule.every(5).minutes.do('A sua função')

while True:
    schedule.run_pending()
    time.sleep(1)
```

a documentação da biblioteca https://schedule.readthedocs.io/en/stable/
Você também pode ver a live do Eduardo Mendes que fala sobre essa biblioteca https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=FjJ1bClIa-o